# excluding one class from a war using ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have a web app that uses RMI, so it includes the RMI interface class but not its implementation. In order to avoid duplicating the interface definition in two places I am trying to keep the RMI server code in the web app's Eclipse project; but the RMI server class must be excluded from the war file since it has a main() method. A jar task in the build.xml and a .spec are used to make the RPM for the RMI Server Daemon.

I tried using an excludes clause in the war task, then in classes,

```
    <war webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml" destfile="${dist.dir}/${ant.project.name}.war">
    <classes dir="${build}" excludes="**/RMIServer.class" />
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}" />
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Built-Date" value="${TODAY}" />
            <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}" />
        </manifest>
    </war>
```

Then in a fileset:

```
    <war webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml" destfile="${dist.dir}/${ant.project.name}.war">
        <classes dir="${build}" />
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}" >
            <exclude name="**/RMIServer*.class"/>
        </fileset>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Built-Date" value="${TODAY}" />
            <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}" />
        </manifest>
    </war>
```

But I have not been able to get it to work - the server class is still in the war/WEB-INF/classes/...

How can I achieve this? Or, is this goal of a single project simply ill-advised?

Comment: Maybe show your attempt at exclusion, and say in what way it did not work?  Someone might be able to advise how to fix that.

Comment: Queestion has nothing specifically to do with RMI.

Comment: not tested but in this code `excludes="**/RMIServer.class"` i think shoud be just `exclude` without `s` at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<classes>` *is* your fileset.  You don't need to use both `<classes>` AND `<fileset>` for class files.  I think what's happening is when you exclude it from one, it is getting included by the other.

Comment: Thanks @whiskeyspider! I didn't realize that, and it was just what I needed to know. After trying several versions it turned out that this one got the right results:
    <fileset dir="${web.dir}" excludes="**/RMIServer.class" />

Comment: Removing the <classes> also fixed the mysterious issue of two copies of every class showing up in war/WEB-INF/classes/. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your last sentence echoes my thoughts. If I had a web server and an RMI server, I'd put them into separate projects, even if one called the other. I'd probably use Maven, or something similar, to help me.

I would be very surprised nowadays to find a project that put two different server process implementations like that into a single Eclipse/IDEA/Maven/Ivy/other project.